# Where is the Android SDK in Android Studio 0.8.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the [latest Canary](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-8-1) and when I install it, I am missing the Android SDK, i.e., it is not in */Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/*. Where did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. You shouldn't download Android Studio from the [Android Studio 0.8.1 page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-8-1).

Instead, download 0.8.0 on [this page](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download) (click "Download Android Studio Beta v0.8.0) and run through the normal DMG install path. After installing in Applications folder, open the app and click "Android Studio" > "Check for updates" to upgrate to 0.8.1. I'm not sure why they didn't included the Android SDK in 0.8.1 build. :P